# using a next button to pass empty SQLite rows

Tags: android, sqlite

and thanks in advance for the help. I'm new to this, and have ran into a snag. My app takes user entered info and stores it in an SQLite database. They can view the records, and there is a "Prev" and "Next" button that views the previous or next record.

The issue I'm having is if the user deletes a record. How would I skip the empty rows? Here is my cleaned up code.

Helper class DBase.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class DBase {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_1 = "a";
public static final String KEY_2 = "b";
public static final String KEY_3 = "c";
public static final String KEY_4 = "d";
public static final String KEY_5 = "e";
public static final String KEY_6 = "f";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_1
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_4
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_5 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_6 + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public DBase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;

}

public DBase open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String a, String b, String c,
        String d, String e, String f) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_1, a);
    cv.put(KEY_2, b);
    cv.put(KEY_3, c);
    cv.put(KEY_4, d);
    cv.put(KEY_5, e);
    cv.put(KEY_6, f);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String[] getRec(long record) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    record = ContactView.record;

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_1, KEY_2,
            KEY_3, KEY_4, KEY_5, KEY_6 };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + record, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        String r1 = c.getString(0);
        String r2 = c.getString(1);
        String r3 = c.getString(2);
        String r4 = c.getString(3);
        String r5 = c.getString(4);
        String r6 = c.getString(5);
        String r7 = c.getString(6);

        String[] rData = { r1, r2, r3, r4, r5,
                r6, r7 };

        return rData;

    }

    return null;
}

// Returns the last record in the database
public long lRec() {

    long lastRec = 0;
    String query = "SELECT ROWID from Table order by ROWID DESC limit 1";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        lastRec = c.getLong(0);
    }
    return lastRec;
}

public void deleteEntry(long lRow) {

    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);

}

}
```

And here is the viewing class, ContactView.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView etSQLva, etSQLvb, etSQLvc, etSQLvd, etSQLve,
        etSQLvf, etSQLvg;
Button bSQLvPrev, bSQLvAdd, bSQLvNext, bSQLvDelete;
static long record = 1;
static long lastRecord;
String[] rRec;
long[] nextRec;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.contactview);

    initialize();
    display();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSQLvPrev:

        recordMinus();
        display();

        break;
    case R.id.bSQLvAdd:

        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.ADD");
        startActivity(i);

        break;
    case R.id.bSQLvNext:

        recordPlus();
        display();

        break;
    case R.id.bSQLvDelete:

        String dRow = etSQLva.getText().toString();
        long lRow = Long.parseLong(dRow);

        DBase db1 = new DBase(this);

        try {
            db1.open();
            db1.deleteEntry(lRow);
            db1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Cannot Delete");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }

        break;

    }
}

public void initialize() {

    etSQLva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLva);
    etSQLvb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLvb);
    etSQLvc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLvc);
    etSQLvd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLvd);
    etSQLve = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLve);
    etSQLvf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLvf);
    etSQLvg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSQLvg);

    bSQLvPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLvPrev);
    bSQLvAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLvAdd);
    bSQLvNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLvNext);
    bSQLvDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLvDelete);

    bSQLvPrev.setOnClickListener(this);
    bSQLvAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    bSQLvNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    bSQLvDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void display() {

    DBase db = new DBase(this);

    db.open();

    rRec = db.getRec(record);

    try {
        lastRecord = db.lRec();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Cannot get last record");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }

    db.close();

    if (rRec != null) {
        etSQLva.setText(rRec[0]);
        etSQLvb.setText(rRec[1]);
        etSQLvc.setText(rRec[2]);
        etSQLvd.setText(rRec[3]);
        etSQLve.setText(rRec[4]);
        etSQLvf.setText(rRec[5]);
        etSQLvg.setText(rRec[6]);
    } else {

    }

}

public void recordPlus() {
    if (record < lastRecord) {
        record++;
    } else {
        record = 1;
    }
}

public void recordMinus() {
    if (record == 1) {
        record = lastRecord;
    } else {
        record--;
    }

}



// Menu code below
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.popup, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mAdd:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.ADD"));
        return true;
    case R.id.mView:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.VIEW"));
        return true;
    case R.id.mAbout:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.ABOUT"));
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
// Menu code end

}
```

How do I make it display the next unempty record when "next" is pressed?

Again, any help would be appreciated, thanks

EDIT: here is my new recordPlus() method code.

```
    public void recordPlus() {
    if (record < lastRecord) {
        record++;
    } else {
        record = 1;
    }
    getData();

    do{
        if (record < lastRecord) {
            record++;
        } else {
            record = 1;
        }
        getData();

    }while (rRec == null);

}
```

and I seperated my display() method which i post below

```
    public void getData() {

    DBase db = new DBase(this);

    db.open();

    rRec = db.getRec(record);

    try {
        lastRecord = db.lRec();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Cannot get last record");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }

    db.close();

}

public void display() {

    if (rRec != null) {
        etSQLva.setText(rRec[0]);
        etSQLvb.setText(rRec[1]);
        etSQLvc.setText(rRec[2]);
        etSQLvd.setText(rRec[3]);
        etSQLve.setText(rRec[4]);
        etSQLvf.setText(rRec[5]);
        etSQLvg.setText(rRec[6]);
    } else {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your display method just have checking code like this (note this is psuedo code):

```
recordPlus(){
  Record currentRecord; 
  do{ 
    ++record;
    currentRecord = getRecord(record);
  }while(isEmptry(currentRecord) && record < lastRecord)
}
```

You'd do something similar for recordMinus.

Comment: the issue is is that if the previous or next record is empty(deleted) when the user presses the prev or next button, I'd want it to go to the next unempty record.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Edited my post.

Comment: Ok, got my recordPlus() method to work skipping empty records, but now i have another issue. it doesn't loop around to the first record once i hit the last record like it used to lol. I'll edit and add the new code above. Same thing happens to the prev button.

Comment: maybe i should seperate "lastRecord = db.lRec();" into it's own method, since it is called everytime i call getData().

Comment: ok, seperating lastRecord = db.lRec() to it's own method didn't work.